# Rotate UICollectionView with expensive Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So I have a `UICollectionView` with different number of `UIImageViews` and each has a custom size and position. On device rotate to landscape it seems kind of jerky, as it removes all the views and adds them again in `CellForItem`

**What I am doing currently:**

```
func updateUI() {

    for item in allItems { item.removeFromSuperview() }
    allItems = []

    for (index, imageData) in imageDataArray.enumerated() {         
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.frame = ...
        imageView.center = ...
        allItems.append(imageView)
    }
}
```

What could I change to make rotation make less calculations or at least don't look glitchy if there's no other way. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using auto layout and flow layout, you could use `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize`

Comment: @user1046037 my cells have fixed size, not sure how would I user automatic size..